# Dealing with XMLHttpRequest exceptions

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Given this code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'http://example.com', false);   
alert(0);
xhr.send();  
alert(1);
```

If `http://example.com` is a cross domain URL it will cause an exception at `xhr.send()`. Then the `alert(1)` is never reached.

How can I write this such that it keeps going to the end even if it is a "bad" URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MDN try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'http://example.com', false);   
alert(0);
try {
    xhr.send();
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
}  
alert(1);
```